# PHP ucwords on echo of MySQL variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php echo from a MySQL query that works fine except that the city is all uppercase in database.

Referencing the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), it appears ucwords should fit the bill?

Works:

```
echo ($row['City']);
```

I tried this but it still shows the city as all uppercase?

```
echo ucwords($row['City']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
echo ucwords(strtolower($row['City']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lowercase the string before you use `ucwords()`:

```
$test = 'HELLO WORLD';

echo ucwords(strtolower($test)); // Hello World
```

**Demo:** https://eval.in/125365

**Note:** [this specific example is actually in the PHP manual](http://php.net/ucwords#refsect1-function.ucwords-examples), always pays to check the manual first.

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ucwords.php

See the docs!

```
 <?php
      $foo = 'hello world!';
      $foo = ucwords ($foo);          // Hello World!

      $bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
      $bar = ucwords($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
      $bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar)); // Hello World!
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you have the `?>` at the end of the line. Try the following:

```
$word = $row['City'];
echo ucwords(strtolower($word));
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out - I forgot the strtolower in the code I had provided